# Mover o eixo no gráfico em R

Tags: r

Preciso fazer alguns gráficos de calor com uma barra de legenda ao lado. Também preciso colocar os eixos. Porém, como eu tive que aumentar um pouco a dimensão do gráfico para a barra de legenda aparecer do lado, o eixo Y dá uma deslocada para longe do desenho do gráfico. Como podemos ver na figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que o eixo Y ficasse bem próximo da figura, como o eixo X está! Estou usando a função image(), será que existe alguma entrada nessa função que consiga mover o eixo sem ter que mudar as dimensões da janela?

Comment: Será mais fácil de ajudar se você disponibilizar seu código e uma parte dos seus dados como explicado [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6701/80049).

Comment: Como disse o Willian, sem você disponibilizar seus dados e o código que você está usando, fica impossível reproduzirmos o problema, até porque, nos exemplos da função `image`, os eixos ficam colados ao gráfico

Comment: Dê uma olhada na função `image.plot` do pacote `fields`.

Comment: Posso sugerir o `ggplot2` fácil de usar e bem completo.
Tutorial: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/